# Solve of differential equation, Bessel equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the following DFs on positive half line. i.e., $r\geq 0$.

$$v''(r)+\frac{2}{r}v'(r)+k^2v(r)=0$$

I tried with Laplace transform but got no luck. I heard this function is called Bessel equation maybe? I am not sure. I wish to got an explicit solution, which for instance, I know it is exist. Please help me to solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Bessel's equation.  The solutions are elementary.

Hint: substitute $v(r) = u(r)/r$.

Comment: ah... yes it is elementary... Thank you! But could you please tell me why you think of this substitution in the first place?

Comment: I think it can be rescaled to a Bessel equation though, which might explain what the OP heard. Also, I'm sure you know this but just so the OP doesn't get a false impression, some Bessel functions *are* elementary.